# Hard Disk Motor... Information

Tags: hard-drive

I removed the motor of my hard disk and this is the connector behind it... I just want to ask what is the purpose of each connector... among that 4 shown below, there could be pair for negative and positive for power... : ) but I dont know where it could be... also, what is the maximum voltage for the motor to function...

[image]

Comment: There is no way to answer that question... it will vary depending on the manufacturer and model of your hard drive.

Comment: Probably at least one pin is used for a wiegand sensor or something of the sort that is used to detect the rotational speed of the drive.

Comment: also, as far as voltage, probably 5v. start at 3.3 to be safe.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I don't know about the wires, but since you don't say what size drive it is:

1. For a 3.5" hard drive, it requires +12V DC to run the motor, AND +5V DC to run the circuit boards. With SATA a third +3.3V DC is also used in addition to the other two.
2. For a typical 2.5" hard drive, it requires +5V DC (often converted to +3.3V DC by an on-board voltage regulator).

http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Serial_ATA

Answer (score 1):

I believe this varies from drive to drive. I would research your exact drive and get some specifics. Then if you can get your hands on a technical manual your life will be much easier.

Answer (score 0):

I am 12 years late but those four large soldered connections are almost certainly Ground/Negative, Phase 1 positive, Phase 2 positive and Phase 3 positive. Three phase drive motors have four connections and their drive wires can also be used by the controller chips/speed controller to detect/control the speed of the motor.

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Comment: Oh great! ...now im trying to figure out why I asked this question 12 years ago lol